# No dynamic page is in script document when I debug my .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug JavaScript code in my .aspx page.  I insert a breakpoint, and press F5 for debugging, but there is no dynamic page created in script documents.

Why does the ASP.NET development server not create the dynamic page?  Any ideas?

Comment: Click over your project and tab to properties windows. Set "Use dynamic ports" to "False" and change the "Port Number" to 8080 then try debugging

Answer (score 0):

One way to force the debugger is to add the `debugger;` command in your JavaScript code where you want the debugger to stop. Something like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
  debugger;
  // do some stuff
}
</script>
```

The debugger will stop on the `debugger`; line and you can step through your JS code.